# How to split string with 1-many spaces and place words in an array

Tags: c#, split, formatting, space

As the title says,

How do i split a string with 1-* numbers of spaces, and place each word in an array

right now I am using `Split(' ')` it works with single spaces, but when it comes to multiple spaces it causes an issue

Here is my sample string:

`0x886fe248 ElanTPCfg.exe          1132   2492      0 --------      1      0 2014-01-20 09:31:10  2014-01-20 09:31:10`

In this example I was only able to get the hexidecimal digit and the executable name, while the others are not read at all

Answer (score 5):

```
void Main()
{
    string s = "0x886fe248 ElanTPCfg.exe          1132   2492      0 --------      1      0 2014-01-20 09:31:10  2014-01-20 09:31:10";
    Console.WriteLine (s.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, this solution worked like a charm and also thanks for the image, it can help future users =)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

```
var output = input.Split(new [] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm =)
but is there a way to not delete my array? I need it for checking reasons,

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string s = @"x886fe248 ElanTPCfg.exe          1132   2492      0 --------      1      0 2014-01-20 09:31:10  2014-01-20 09:31:10";
string[] strArr = Regex.Split(s, @"\s+");
```

`\s+` is one or more whitespace character(s).